# Unity loading scenes from the tag of the box collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I want to load different unity scenes based on the tag the game object has with a box collider 2D like a level loader. I have 4 "doors" (the game object with the collider) named top for top bottom for bottom left for left and right for right so I want to load the scene named bottom for the bottom door.

This is the code that does not work what I have currently

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string topScene;
    [SerializeField] private string bottomScene;
    [SerializeField] private string leftScene;
    [SerializeField] private string rightScene;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (collision.CompareTag("top"))
            {
                LoadScene(topScene);
            }
            else if (collision.CompareTag("bottom"))
            {
                LoadScene(bottomScene);
            }
            else if (collision.CompareTag("left"))
            {
                LoadScene(leftScene);
            }
            else if (collision.CompareTag("right"))
            {
                LoadScene(rightScene);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }
}
```

[image: my hierarchy]

[image: my game scene]

Comment: Did you debug if the execution arrives to         SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
 line? or where is the execution ending?

Comment: what exactly isnt happening? are those scenes in your build?

Comment: yes i made those scenes now i want to load them when i go trough the collider

Comment: You check `if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) { if (collision.CompareTag("top")) ...` => Both conditions check the tag of the **same** object ([`collision.CompareTag`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/2d9918cf6dc3194015d75bd9845555f59a0015e4/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs#L197) basically is just a shorthand implementation for `collision.gameObject.CompareTag`), the one you collided with. How is any object supposed to have the tag `Player` and at the same time the tag `top`? => This seems to be a clear "typo" / user issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **gameObject.CompareTag("top")** on all Conditions accept First One.
Because collision.gameobject.CompareTag("??") && collision.CompareTag("??")
is same thing. And you compare 2 tags on same gameobject while gameobject contains only one tag at a time. So during Collision, you can check that if collision gameobject having a Player tag and in nested condition you can also check that it contains top, left, right, bottom tag which is not right.

[image]

Comment: While most probably true you might want to consider to extend this a bit with an explanation ;) .. for example [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782928/unity-loading-scenes-from-the-tag-of-the-box-collider#comment137128295_77782928)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).